# MySQL sum up a column to a LIMIT and return sum value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and I'm trying to sum up a column up to a specific point with say, `LIMIT`, and then return the sum value, but it's not working. This is what I have:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die ("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT sum(donation_count) FROM (SELECT donation_count FROM users LIMIT 9) AS value_sum";

$result = $conn->query ($sql);  

if ($result-> num_rows> 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<div>'".$row['value_sum']."'</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It seems to me that you are arbitrarily collecting any 9 rows of data, then summing these values.  Is this trustworthy for your project?  Are all of the `donation_count` values the same?  I'm with Strawberry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(donation_count) as value_sum FROM (SELECT donation_count  FROM users LIMIT 9) AS temp
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm totally new to this. I tried your solution and replaced $row['value_sum'] with my substitute for your 'temp' (say: $row['temp']). Still not working. Maybe I did it wrong. Any further help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to change $row['value_sum'] in your code.use my request in your code and nolthing else, it should work